# RegEx validation for monetary value in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Must accept:

> **1,111.11** or **1000.00**

Must not accept:

> **,111** or **1,11,11** or **1.00.00**

Currently I have this code:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
    //textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

which only accepts number

Comment: You can use masked edit extender from Ajax Control Toolkit if it is a web form application. http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: Should the valid numbers be 4 digists prior to the decimal point & two digits after decimal point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to validate yourself using RegExes, what if you use some built in functionality to get the desired result.

One way would be to:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
decimal currency;
if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.text, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out currency))
{
   // Its a valid currency value
}
else {
  // NOt a valid currency.
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid currency.");
}
```

This would work in scenarios where you wan't to use the application for a different culture as well (provided that you don't hardcode "en-US" of course).

Read more about [Decimal.TryParse here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES") to disallow 1,11,11 but it accepts 1.11.11 that en-US checks

Answer (score 1):

I'm no pro at regex, but this seemed to work for me.

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+(\.\d{2})?
```

Comment: "[\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+(.\d{2})?]":Unrecognized escape sequence error

Comment: \ is an escape sequence in C#. You'd need to make it \\d instead of \d. My apologies.

Comment: Or just add an at (@) at the beginning of the string.